# Multirow curly bracket and replicating a figure

Tags: math-mode

I want to recreate an equation, and I am not sure how to go about it.  The features I'm interested in are the double row bracket and the aligned >> and << on the Right.

[image: Equation to replicate]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  A structure like this is handled by the `cases` environment from `amsmath`.  As for aligning the right-hand side, since the material preceding the greater/less operators is the same in both lines, no special coding is required.

Comment: Unrelated, but in the image the "max" looks more bound to the "/" than to the "E". Or, if you want, the "/" looks more bound to the "max" than to the following "E".

Answer (score 1):

The simplest possible solution is using the `cases` environment from the `amsmath` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \lambda_{Np} = \lambda_p
  \begin{cases}
    1 + 3 (E_{\mathrm{max}} / E_0)^2 / 16, & E_{\mathrm{max}} / E_0 \ll 1 \\
    (2 / \pi) (E_{\mathrm{max}} / E_0 + E_0 / E_{\mathrm{max}}), & E_{\mathrm{max}} / E_0 \gg 1, \\
  \end{cases}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For more complex needs you can have a look at the `alignedat` environment (also from `amsamth`) together with half-open delimiters but in the situation at hand there is not really a need for it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \lambda_{Np} = \lambda_p
  \left\{
  \begin{alignedat}{2}
    &1 + 3 (E_{\mathrm{max}} / E_0)^2 / 16, & \quad E_{\mathrm{max}} / E_0 &\ll 1 \\
    &(2 / \pi) (E_{\mathrm{max}} / E_0 + E_0 / E_{\mathrm{max}}), & E_{\mathrm{max}} / E_0 &\gg 1, \\
  \end{alignedat}
  \right.
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

The output is pretty much that same as above.

Comment: +1, but `{\mathrm{max}}` --- > `{\max}` ...

Comment: @Zarko I highly doubt that this is supposed to be the `\max` operator.